# Split the PDF file into image files using c# 2008?

Tags: c#, pdf

In my PDF I have a page containing 10 images.

I want to split the PDF file as 10 individual image files and save them in a separate folder.

Please give me an idea or a sample solution.

Im using c# 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant after a year, but I just did it recently myself, so I figured i'd just answer anyway.

First, you'll need Ghostscript (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/) a venerable PS/PDF parse/render/convert engine. After installation, head to `%PROGRAMDATA\gs\bin\` (or x86 if you're running a x64 system) and grab the `gsdll32.dll` and copy it to your /bin folder.

You'll then need a closed source PDF library called *Super PDF2Image Converter* (http://www.softwaresigloxxi.com/downloading_superPDF2ImageConverter.html), grab the `Pdf2Image.dll` from the .zip file and copy it to your /bin folder.

Here's a quick example on how to convert multiple PDF pages to images using those two libraries:

```
using Pdf2Image;
```

--

```
  const string _filename = "/3.pdf";
  // Instantiate the component
  var p2i = new Pdf2ImageConverter(_filename);

  // Get page count of a PDF file
  int pages = p2i.GetPageCount();
  Response.Write(pages);

  // loops through each page
  for (int i = 1; i < pages; i++)
  {
   // Get size of any page
   int width, height;
   p2i.GetPageSize(i, out width, out height);

   // converts the page to PNG format (returns bitmap object with original size)
   var pdfimage = p2i.GetImage(i, width, Pdf2ImageFormat.PNG);
   pdfimage.Save(string.Format("/{0}.png",i));
   pdfimage.Dispose();
  }
```

Depending on your hardware, it shouldnt take any longer than a couple of seconds per page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to extract images from a specific page in a PDF file and save these images into separate files.

If I am right then you may want to take a look at [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). Here is a sample that shows how to extract images from a PDF page into specified folder:

```
static void ExtractImagesFromPdfPageIntoFolder()
{
    string pathToPdf = "";
    int pageIndex = 0;
    string outputFolder = "";
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pathToPdf))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Pages[pageIndex].Images.Count; i++)
        {
            string imageName = string.Format("image{0}", i);
            string outputName = Path.Combine(outputFolder, imageName);
            string savedPath = pdf.Pages[pageIndex].Images[i].Save(outputName);
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.